# Type error: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, typeerror, opencv

Hello I have been trying to import an image from desktop to the jupyter notebook using opencv. I am getting the following error message at the end **Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float** . My code is as follows:

```
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = cv.imread("dog.jpg")
im_1 = cv.cvtColor(im,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

> error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 im_1 = cv.cvtColor(im,cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
>
> error: OpenCV(4.5.3)
> C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_xlv4eex\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182:
> error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
> 'cv::cvtColor'

```
 plt.imshow(im)
```

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap,
> norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent,
> filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, data, **kwargs)    2907
> filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample,    2908
> url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
> -> 2909         **kwargs)    2910     sci(__ret)    2911     return __ret
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_*init*_.py in inner(ax,
> data, *args, **kwargs)    1359     def inner(ax, *args, data=None,
> **kwargs):    1360         if data is None:
> -> 1361             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)    1362     1363         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py in imshow(self,
> X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin,
> extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)    5607
> resample=resample, **kwargs)    5608
> -> 5609         im.set_data(X)    5610         im.set_alpha(alpha)    5611         if im.get_clip_path() is None:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
> 699                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
> 700             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
> --> 701                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
> 702
> 703         if self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] == 1:
>
> TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float

Please if someone could help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So yes I finally found out the answer was that I didn't specify the correct file path in cv.imread() instead of cv.imread("dogs.jpg") I would have written full path (C:/......)
etc